# Can't call Close on Word document without getting a warning

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

I can't call `Close` my opened word document:

```
docs.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges, nullobject, nullobject);
```

or `Quit` on the application:

```
wordObject.Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
```

Without getting this compiler warning:

> Warning   1   Ambiguity between method
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application.Quit(ref object, ref
>   object, ref object)' and non-method
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event.Quit'. Using
>   method group.

And full code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                object file = pathToFile; //this is the path
                object nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = wordObject.Documents.Open(file, nullobject, nullobject, nullobject,
                nullobject, nullobject, nullobject, nullobject, nullobject, nullobject, nullobject, nullobject, nullobject, nullobject, nullobject, nullobject);
```

Using Office library 15.

Comment: Have you tried this? `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event.Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);`

Comment: @vallabha: You can't call a method on an interface declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a warning and you can ignore it. The problem is in the definition of the actual `Application` interface and it's underlying interfaces in .NET. You can circumvent this warning by casting it to one of the two types proposed in the warning:

```
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)wordObject).Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
```

This will disambiguate the method call. If you don't do this, there is no harm done.